# Is GROUP BY needed in the following correlated subquery?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, having, correlated-subquery

Given scenario:

```
table fd  
(cust_id, fd_id) primary-key and amount  

table loan  
(cust_id, l_id) primary-key and amount
```

I want to list all customers who have a fixed deposit with an amount less than the sum of all their loans.

Query:

```
SELECT cust_id
  FROM fd
    WHERE amount
     <
    (SELECT sum(amount)
        FROM loan
          WHERE fd.cust_id = loan.cust_id);

OR should we use

SELECT cust_id
  FROM fd
    WHERE amount
     <
    (SELECT sum(amount)
        FROM loan
          WHERE fd.cust_id = loan.cust_id group by cust_id);
```

A customer can have multiple loans but one FD is considered at a time.

Comment: There DEFINITELY ARE multiple cust_id (primary-key includes l_id)...! Now what should be the case..??

Comment: That is not a problem, the query *expects* multiple rows per `cust_id` in the table `loan`. In the subquery there can be only one distinct `cust_id`, so the `GROUP BY` (your question) makes no difference. However, as there can be multiple `cust_id` in the table `fd` to begin with. May or may not be what you want ...

Comment: So sir, can we conclude that the first query will give an aggregate function, i.e., for a matched cust_id, four inner cust_id's amount get summed up? In other words, is it sure to give 'GROUPed BY' data?

Comment: The subquery definitely yields *one* aggregated value per base row with either of your two queries. The base query can result in multiple rows per `cust_id`, though, as `cust_id` is not unique. Each row's `amount` is still checked against the sum of all amounts for the matching `cust_id` in table `loan`. We are not in the clear if that is what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GROUP BY` *can* be omitted in this case, because there is only (one) aggregate function(s) in the `SELECT` list and all rows are guaranteed to belong to the same group of `cust_id` ( by the `WHERE` clause).

The aggregation will be over all rows with matching `cust_id` in both cases. So both queries are correct.

---

This would be <strike>a cleaner</strike> another way to implement the same thing:

```
SELECT fd.cust_id
FROM   fd
JOIN   loan USING (cust_id)
GROUP  BY fd.cust_id, fd.amount
HAVING fd.amount < sum(loan.amount)
```

There is *one difference*: rows with identical `(cust_id, amount)` in `fd` only appear once in the result of my query, while they would appear multiple times in the original.

Either way, if there is no matching row with a *non-null* `amount` in table `loan`, you get **no rows at all**. I assume you are aware of that.

Comment: 'Can' GROUP BY be omitted... or 'Must' be it omitted?

Comment: @popstack: It *can*. Both versions are correct. I would omit it, though. It's just cruft in this case.

Comment: +1, though I think you could omit fd.amount from the GROUP BY clause in your rewrite.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I have to include `fd.amount` in the GROUP BY because I compare the non-aggregated value in the HAVING clause. A useful variant would be `HAVING (max(fd.amount) < sum(loan.amount)`, but the OP did not define what he tries to achieve exactly, so that may or may not be what he wants.

Answer (score 2):

There are no need for `GROUP BY` since you filtered data by `cust_id`. In any case inner query will return the same result.

Comment: It is supposed to return multiple rows each having (customer, total-loan). Now?

Comment: @popstack. Ok. For the first variant: subquery will filter all fields where `fd.cust_id = loan.cust_id and` (for each possible `fd.cust_id`) then sum values for `amount`. Second varint: filter all fields `fd.cust_id = loan.cust_id` (for each possible `fd.cust_id`) then group them to have uniq `cust_id`. But there are already all fields have uniq `cust_id`, since you filtered them.

Answer (score 2):

No, it isn't, because you calculate `sum(amount)` for customer with `id = fd.cust_id`, so for a single customer.

However, if somehow your subquery calculate sum for more than one customer, the `group by` would cause the subquery to generate more than one row and this will cause the condition(<) to fail, and thus, the query to fail.

Comment: I did not get any error as such. Multiple customers are having different loans and are present in sample data... Is GROUP BY needed?

Comment: my first two words: "it isn't" nedeed.

Answer (score 1):

A query with an aggregate like `sum` but without a `group by` will output one group.  The aggregates will be computed over all matching rows.

A subquery in a condition clause is only allowed to return one row.  If the subquery returned multiple rows, what would the following expression mean?

```
where 1 > (... subquery ...)
```

So the `group by` must be omitted; you would even get an error for your second query.

N.B. When you specify [all, any, or some](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178543.aspx) a subquery can return multiple rows:

```
where 1 > ALL (... subquery ...)
```

But it's easy to see why that doesn't make sense in your case; you'd compare one customer's data to that of another.

Comment: A correlated subquery runs as many times as the outer query... It is a report like "customer, total-loan"... Now?